# Upgrade to 103-generic Broke Opera Videos

Tags: 16.04, video, youtube, opera, h264

Currently running Opera 49.0.2725.39 with `ffmpeg 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1` on Ubuntu 16.04. When I updated Ubuntu from `4.4.0.101-generic` to `4.4.103-generic` it broke the video playback in Opera. Now I get a message `install flash or H.264 decoder to support player.` I've tried everything I can find regarding installing flash or updating ffmpeg, but all that stuff is out of date and none of it works. Thanks in advance for any help that actually works.

Comment: See this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/986162/after-opera-update-websites-with-flash-doesnt-work

Comment: SOLVED - Use Synaptic to un-install Opera and then install Opera-Beta 50.0.2762.35.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem that might be what is happening to you. What happened was that Ubuntu updated the package *chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra* to version 63, of which Opera needs a specific version, without which codec H.264 doesn't work.

You can check in Synaptic Manager which version of *chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra* you have installed. Then, on Opera's address bar enter **opera://about/** where you can check the Chromium version it needs.

Then, you could try installing version 61 of the chromium package. That worked for me. You can download it here: 
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/

After version 61 is installed, in Synaptic Manager find and select the package and on the menu go to *Package > Force Version*, there select version 61. Apply changes to downgrade from version 63.

I hope that helps.

Comment: chromium-codecs-ffmpeg.extra 63.0.3239.84-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (latest version) is what was installed. Opera says it wants: Chrome/62.0.3202.94. http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser has no version 62, so I downloaded chromium-codecs-ffmpeg_61.0.3163.100-0ubuntu1.1378_i386.deb and installed it. The auto-installer indicated at the end of the install that I had version 63 but Synaptic verified that 61 was installed. Killed Opera and restarted it. Same error message and still no video.

Comment: Yes, there is no version 62. Use version 61 instead. You have to force Synaptic to use the version you installed. I updated my original post with the proper instructions. 

Sorry about that.