# After Opera update websites with flash doesn't work

Tags: 16.04, flash, opera

Website such as https://coub.com doesn't work after opera update.

- Version:  49.0.2725.56 - Opera is up to date
- Update stream:    Stable
- System:   Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (x86_64; Unity)

Running opera from console I found error.

`opera MEDIA_ERROR_LOG_ENTRY {"error":"FFmpegDemuxer: open context failed"}`

Comment: Same as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986059/upgrade-to-103-generic-broke-opera-videos)?

Comment: @pomsky, it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to replace file `libffmpeg.so` in the opera directory with the working one.

#### New way

1. Get ffmpeg

```
sudo apt install chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
```

2. Replace opera file with our file

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/chromium-browser/libffmpeg.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/
```

3. Restart Opera

**And every time when Opera will be updated, run**

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/chromium-browser/libffmpeg.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/
```

#### Old way (but stable)

1. Download latest release `[version]-linux-x64.zip` file from [here](https://github.com/iteufel/nwjs-ffmpeg-prebuilt/releases) (or try another release)
2. Find opera directory using `which`

   ```
    user@host:~$ which opera
    /usr/bin/opera
    user@host:~$ ls -l /usr/bin/opera 
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 дек  9 01:04 /usr/bin/opera -> ../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/opera
   ```
3. Extract file `libffmpeg.so` from the archive you downloaded.
4. Move lib file to the opera directory `sudo cp -f ~/Downloads/libffmpeg.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/opera`
5. Restart Opera